# Motion Tracking - Upward Tilting Shot

Tags: tracking

I've been trying to motion track a footage that I can't wrap my head around.

It's a handheld shot that slowly tilts upwards - towards the sky. I have plenty of trackers until the sky is revealed and then I have nothing to track. So half of my footage is devoid of tracking markers.

3D objects I place inside the footage stay grounded until the sky is revealed and they just slip out of their place.

How can I solve this ? Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: I think you’ll probably need to manually animate the camera during those sections where you don’t have enough tracking points. You can do this either by manually filling in the tracks by moving the trackers manually or by disabling the camera tracking constraint for that section and keyframing the camera motion. It will be a challenge getting the transition suitably smooth but this will depend on your actual footage.

Comment: Thanks Rich ! Does this mean that I have to manually place a marker and then reposition the centre frame by frame ? Do this for several markers positioned in the sky ?

Comment: Yes - manually faking the track in that way is one way of doing it. Another way would be to keyframe the camera for that section - and use the constraint Influence to control when the camera is controlled by the track and when it’s controlled by your keyframes.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying - at least conceptually. But I'm very new to all this so I have no clue as to how I would approach this. Do you know of any tutorials that show how it's done ?

Comment: Hey Rich, After a lot of guesswork I finally managed to disable the Camera constraint by keyframing it's influence. However, when I bring the influence down to 0, the Origin and my 3D model jump out of place. What do I do know ? On a positive note, I also managed to animate the camera that closely resembles the original shot.

Comment: Rich, I looked at my project again. Instead of my 3D model jumping I now realize that the 3D camera leaves it's position as soon as the Camera Constraint influence comes down to 0. Is there a way to copy the camera's 'final' position so that I can pin it exactly where it was before ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (I've been too busy) but I believe 'Apply Visual Transforms' will help (although I've not managed to actually try it with tracking constraints). Get the camera to the transition point and press CTRL+A for the 'Apply' menu and select Visual Transform. This should takes it's current position (including all constraints) and use that for the 'at rest' position of the camera. When you now reduce the influence to zero you should get the camera staying at that one place. This will work for a single transition but is more complicated if need multiple transitions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you have no trackers in the sky, blender has no information to determin the right position. You might have to reshoot the footage with a wider shot where the trackers stay visible and cut to the sky in post production.